# Метод ветвей и границ задача об экспериментаторе

Tags: c++

Добрый день. Не получается написать программу на метод ветвей и границ. Задача: профессор поднимается по очереди на каждый этаж некоего дома и сбрасывает оттуда транзисторы. Заведомо известно, что с первого этажа транзисторы не бьются. Пусть, упав с какого-то этажа какой-то транзистор разбился, тогда профессор спускается вниз, подбирает уцелевшие и снова скидывает их с каждого этажа. Нужно найти минимальный этаж, с которого всё бьётся и посчитать минимальное количество подъёмов по лестнице.
Написала рекурсивную функцию MBB, но не вижу ошибки. Первые подъём и спуск работают нормально, а потом нет. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что не так.

```
void MBB(int floor, int summ, int numbers_of_trans, int delta_of_floors) {

    summ += delta_of_floors;

    file << "Встали на этаж: " << floor << "\n";
    file << "Текущая сумма: " << summ << "\n";
    file << "Количество транзисторов на руках: " << numbers_of_trans << "\n";
    file << "Количество хороших транзисторов внизу: " << good_trans << "\n";

    numbers_of_trans--;
    file << "Скинули один транзистор\n";

    if (floor<durable) {
        good_trans++;
        file << "Транзистор не разбился\n";
        file << "Количество транзисторов на руках: " << numbers_of_trans << "\n";
        file << "Количество хороших транзисторов внизу: " << good_trans << "\n";
        for (int i = floor + 1; i <= numbers_of_floors; i++) {
            MBB(i, summ, numbers_of_trans, i - floor);
            file << "\n";
        }

    }
    else {
        file << "Транзистор разбился\n";
        file << "Количество транзисторов на руках: " << numbers_of_trans << "\n";
        file << "Количество хороших транзисторов внизу: " << good_trans << "\n";
        if (best_summ == -1) {
            best_summ = summ;
            best_floor = floor;
            file << "Текущая лучшая сумма: " << best_summ << "\n";
            file << "Текущий лучший этаж: " << best_floor << "\n\n";
            floor = 0;
            if (good_trans > 0) {
                summ += floor;
                numbers_of_trans += good_trans;
                file << "Подняли " << good_trans << " транзисторов\n";
                file << "Количество транзисторов на руках: " << numbers_of_trans << "\n";
                good_trans = 0;
                file << "Количество хороших транзисторов внизу: " << good_trans << "\n\n";
            }
            else {
                file << "Транзисторы на руках и внизу закончились!!\n\n";
                return;
            }
            for (int i = floor + 1; i <= numbers_of_floors; i++) {
                MBB(i, summ, numbers_of_trans, i - floor);
                file << "\n";
            }

        }

    }

}
void ConsoleEnter() {

    cout << "Введите количество этажей: ";
    cin >> numbers_of_floors;
    cout << "Введите число транзисторов: ";
    cin >> numbers_of_trans;
    durable = rand() % numbers_of_floors + 2; // изначальная прочность, которая должна меняться, если будет найдена прочность меньше

    while (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Попробуйте снова.";
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
    }

    good_trans = 0;

    best_summ = -1;
    best_floor = -1;

    MBB(1, 0, numbers_of_trans, 1);

    cout << "Этаж, с которого транзистор точно разобьётся: " << best_floor << "\n";
    cout << "Лучшее число подъёмов: " << best_summ;
}
```

Comment: а метод ветвей и границ вам по заданию нужен? Подобная задача решается легче динамическим программированием.

Comment: нужно и то, и то, динамическое программирование по этой задаче -- уже следующее задание